# How can I observe changes to opacity of a UIView (possibly via its CALayer property?)

Tags: swift, uiview, calayer, key-value-observing

Title is the basic question.  Trying to get notified when the opacity on a view(s layer) changes.

This is allowed...

```
addedView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(isHidden), options: [.old, .new], context: nil)
```

But this doesn't compile...

```
addedView.layer.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(opacity), options: [.old, .new], context: nil)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you writing this code in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#ID549):

> The property name must be a reference to a property that is available
> in the Objective-C runtime. [...] For example:
>
> ```
> // ...
> let c = SomeClass(someProperty: 12)
> let keyPath = #keyPath(SomeClass.someProperty)
>
> if let value = c.value(forKey: keyPath) {
>     print(value)
> }
> ```
>
> When you use a key-path string expression within a class, you can
> refer to a property of that class by writing just the property name,
> without the class name.
>
> ```
> extension SomeClass {
>     func getSomeKeyPath() -> String {
>         return #keyPath(someProperty)
>     }
> }
> print(keyPath == c.getSomeKeyPath())
> // Prints "true"
> ```

So really, the property name in `#keyPath(...)` should be qualified *in general*. Unless the property is in the same class as the `#keyPath` expression, you should qualify the property name with its enclosing class name. This makes sense, because how else is the compiler going to know *which* `isHidden` property you mean?

`#keyPath(isHidden)` *just so happens to work* because the class in which you are writing this in also *happens to have* a `isHidden` property (probably a `UIView` subclass?).

You should do:

```
#keyPath(CALayer.opacity)
```

for `opacity`

Comment: Perfect!  And you answered one of the other questions I had... why, if it's just a string, does it matter where it's defined? Now I know, and others will too!  Thanks!